# How to export env value with comma in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins configuration doesn't allow commas in export commands, like:

```json
export GOPROXY=xxxx.com,indirect
```

Thus, how to export env correctly with comma?

Comment: What do you mean by "Jenkins configuration"? What do you mean by "doesn't allow"? What error, or unexpected behaviour, are you seeing? And what happens if you try the obvious step of adding quotation marks, i.e. `export GOPROXY="xxxx.com,indirect"`? (I *presume* that's what you wanted to achieve? Your question doesn't make this particularly clear.)

Comment: @TomLord `cloud.google.com/go@v0.46.3: invalid $GOPROXY setting: cannot have comma`  Using `""` still report same error

Comment: I googled your error, and [this is the top result](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/33725). You've using go version `0.46.3`, and this feature is available from `1.13` onwards. I don't think the issue has got anything to do with Jenkins. I think the environmental variable is being set exactly as you expect, and the issue is purely that your version of `go` does not support a `GOPROXY` in that format.

Comment: @TomLord 3q so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should use `"` character around the value of exported variable.

   `export GOPROXY="xxxx.com,indirect"`
2. As @Tom Lord has written in comment section your problem is related to the `go` version (Not to Jenkins).